# Total price changes to zero after selecting option

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options, grand-total

I recently updated from Magento 1.6.1 to Magento 1.9.2.1 and I noticed that the total price of a product changes to 0,00 when I select an option (https://sportinngerritsen.nl/professional-supreme-elite-200-mtr-amber). When I continue to my shopping cart, the price is correct. I've tried a few things I found on the internet like changing a peace of code in the file option`app/design/frontend/default/sportinn/template/catalog/product/options/view/options.phtml`:

```
price += parseFloat(this.config[optionId][selectOption.value].priceValue);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't make a difference. Who can help me with this?

Comment: It seems an event has been hooked from your magento to change the price. Did you check the simple product prices assigned to that config. product?

Comment: It happens with every single product, so that doesn't really change anything if that's what you mean.

Comment: There are a few `JavaScript` errors in your product page, like `Uncaught ReferenceError: spConfig is not defined`. This may cause the incorrect price after selecting an option. Like @hellimac suggests in his answer you could temporarily switch to the RWD theme or Default theme and see if this is theme related.

Comment: Try to go through these steps: Restore the default theme, disable all your modules and try again. If the issue *still* happens, then you must have edited some core JS files. Download a fresh copy, and replace the content of `/js` to see if  the issue is fixed

Answer (score 3):

Try changing your theme to either "rwd" or "base". I think what is happening is that the theme you are currently using was made for Magento 1.6.1 and doesn't comport the same class / DOM architecture as required by the Javascript files of the version 1.9.2.

If it works with the theme of Magento 1.9.2, you will have either to explore the JS files to see what classes is looked for, or remake the files of your theme based on the 1.9.2 theme files.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the theme to rwd or base didn't make a difference. I did check if the spConfig has anything to do with is by following these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22460719/magento-1-7-custom-options-not-updating-price
It made the error go away, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't look in the right place apparently.. The pricing bug DOESN'T happen when changing to the base/default theme.. It looks like it is my theme after all.

Comment: Try looking at the DOM/class differences between your current theme and the default theme for the product view page. I already had to do that, re-include default functionalities on a modified theme, and I know it's not really funny... Courage !

Comment: Do you know what class/file I'm supposed to be looking for? Magento is a big package and I'm quite new to it.

Comment: It would be great if I could have an answer to this :)